# Using \@currenvir in \ifthenelse

Tags: environments, ifthenelse

I have looked over several questions on these forums but I seem to be missing something.

I am writing a macro in LaTeX to perform one function if it is used inside an enumerate environment, another function if outside. To do this I am using an `\ifthenelse` statement and testing the environment using `\@currenvir`, which if my other searches are correct is where LaTeX stores the name of the current environment, however it isn't working. On using a minimal example it turns out that I am only ever getting a false result from the statement.

Can anybody point out where I am going wrong? Here is a minimal example which always turns out false:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentEnvironment}{% Test what environment we are in
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\@currenvir}{enumerate}}{TRUE}{FALSE}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item item1
\item Are we in enumerate: \currentEnvironemnt
\item item3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Obviously I'm using the wrong macro to test the environment, or I am using the right macro incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your test works, but you wrote `\currentEnvironemnt` instead of `\currentEnvironment`, but after correcting that typo, `TRUE` is printed. You can try `\newcommand{\currentEnvironment}{%
  \def\@testenvir{enumerate}
  \ifx\@currenvir\@testenvir
  TRUE%
  \else
  FALSE%
  \fi
}` as well

Comment: THANK YOU! Such a simple error has been causing me so much headache.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to a simple typo and has been solved in comments.